# Rccognise last working day and change substring of cell value

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2013

I am trying to change 2 dates ('10-06-19'!F333+'10-06-19'!Y555) in cell value to last working day.

I have a list in Excel of the public holidays which can be maintained.

I have the code to recognise weekends + holidays. Could someone help with code for  changing (datepart) substring of cell value with value of Wrkdate.

```
Sub ChangeSubstringOfDate() 
    Dim WrkDate
    WrkDate = Date

    If (Application.Weekday(Date - 1, 2) = 7) Then      '  for  Sunday
        WrkDate = WrkDate - 2
    Else
        If (Application.Weekday(Date - 1, 2) = 6) Then  '  for  Saturday
            WrkDate = WrkDate - 1      
        Else
            'check for  for  holidays
            WrkDate = Application.WorksheetFunction.WorkDay(Date, -1, Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A:A"))
        End If
    End If

    Range("C7").Value = Format(WrkDate - 1, "dd mm yy")  
    '10-06-19'!F333+'10-06-19'!Y555-- change date to i.e. 06-06-19.    
End Sub
```

Comment: https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-workday-function

Comment: Thanks I have update my code. Just need help with updating cell value with value of Wrkdate now.

Answer (score 0):

Last WorkDay

```
Sub Test()
    MsgBox CDate(Evaluate("WORKDAY(TODAY(),-1)"))
End Sub
```